# $\int_V\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate $$\int_V\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dxdy$$ with $$V:=\{(x,y) : \pi^2 \le x^2+y^2 \le 4\pi^2\}$$
I know how $\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ looks like:

[image: Plot of $\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$]

Now the integral is the volume of the hatched area. It is like the body of rotation of the sine function between $0$ and $\pi$ and hence is calculated with $vol = \pi \int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{2}$.

But there must be an (easy) way to calculate $\int_V\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dxdy$ without knowing anything about the graph.

Any help with that is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use polar coordinates:
$$x^2+y^2=r^2,\ \ dxdy=r\,drd\theta.$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
&\int\limits_V\sin\big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\,dxdy\\
=\ &\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{r=\pi}^{r=2\pi}\sin(r)\,r\,drd\theta\\
=\ &2\pi\left(\left[-\cos(r)\,r\frac{}{}\right]_\pi^{2\pi}+\int_\pi^{2\pi}\cos(r)\,dr\right)\\
=\ &2\pi(-3\pi+0)\frac{}{}\\
=\ &-6\pi^2. 
\end{align*}
The integral is negative because the volume is under the $xy$ plane (as you can see in your graph).

Comment: As a further sanity check, since the annulus has area $3\pi^3$ the mean of $\sin r$ is $-2/\pi$, which had modulus $<1$.

Answer (score 1):

If ever there was a integral begging for polar coordinates, this is it. In these coordinates, your integral is
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\theta\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}r\sin(r)\mathrm dr\\
=2\pi \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}r\sin(r)\mathrm dr
$$
you may proceed by parts.